# 비빔밥 - Examples of 비비다 outside of "Bi-bim-bap"

Tags: conversation, written, examples

I love [비빔밥 - Bi-bim-bap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibimbap).  It's a traditional Korean dish where the items in a bowl are served to the customer, and the customer then takes a Korean spoon and mixes it all together.

The verb `비비다` (to mix) attaches to the noun `밥` (rice/food) to make the name:

> *비비다 + 밥 =*  **비빔밥**

Now please don't answer saying "비비다 means to mix".  That's not the question - that's the background to the question.

### Outside of 비빔밥 what uses of the 동작동사 *비비다* might be heard or read?

Comment: 요새는 유행어로도 씁니당. "어제 저그로 테란한테 비벼봤는데 역시 이기긴 힘들더라." 이런식으로

Comment: @James please add that as an answer and expound upon the meaning a bit more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've mostly heard 비비다 used for food and for body parts:

> 밥 비벼 주세요! - Please mix my rice [with the sauce] - note this doesn't have to be 비빔밥, but any sauce; my children ask for it with 불고기 sauce.
>
> 눈을 비비다 - to rub your eyes
>
> 눈 비비지 마! - Don't rub your eyes!
>
> 손을 비비다 - to rub your hands

Comment: as an aside, i asked my wife to hurry home so we could eat 비빔밥, so i was all like `비비자` which i meant in terms of making some 비빔밥, but she giggled and said 밥을 비벼 아니면 나와 너 비벼?